# VBA printout activates printed worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I use the following procedure for multiple worksheets:

```
Sub PrintTask(ByVal wsName As String, ByVal pageCount As Long)
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(wsName)
        .PrintOut From:=1, To:=pageCount, Copies:=1, Preview:=False
        .DisplayPageBreaks = False
    End With
End Sub
```

It activates each worksheet, while I would like to stay on the worksheet from which I run the macro all the time, not just return to it after printing has finished. Is it even possible?

Comment: It' would appear it's going to `Select` the sheets being printed anyway. A workaround would be to include the current sheet in the list of printed sheets: `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(Array(ActiveSheet.Name, wsName)).PrintOut` and set `From` to the number of pages the current sheet has + 1. Then it will select the two sheets (the active sheet on the screen will not change because the first of the selected two is already active) and will not actually print the current sheet. The drawback is that you have to know exactly how many printed pages the active sheet has, or the printout will be wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure that `ScreenUpdating` is set to `False` before calling your procedure, and you won't notice <sup>*</sup> the "activation" of the other sheet:

```
Sub Test
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    PrintTask "Sheet1", 3
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

( <sup>*</sup> Unless the other sheet has something in its `Worksheet_Activate` event handler.)

Comment: I haven't even considered this solution, as I needed to interact with initial worksheet between printing tasks (button click to cancel them), but it came out that 'Application.ScreenUpdating = False' allows me to do this, so silly of me.